# Want answer of this 8086 assembly code and values?

Tags: assembly, x86

I am trying to create a program that display this in assembly 8086:

```
First Name: Nada
last Name: masoud
```

I need to know how to add new line for last Name: masoud

```
org 100h

mov   ax,0b800h
mov   ds,ax 

linefeed db 13, 10, "$"

mov [02h], 'F'
mov [04h], 'i'
mov [06h], 'r'
mov [08h], 's'
mov [0ah], 't'
mov [0ch], ' '
mov [010h], 'N'
mov [012h], 'a'
mov [014h], 'm'
mov [016h], 'e'
mov [018h], ':'
mov [01ah], 'N'
mov [01ch], 'a'
mov [01eh], 'd'
mov [020h], 'a'

mov ah, 09
mov dx, offset linefeed
int 21h

mov   ax,0b800h
mov   ds,ax
mov [0a2h], ' '
mov [04h], 'a'
ret
```

Comment: our professor need us to use this type of writing code to display first name and last name and id as letters per each line so i start the first line by this and dont know how to add new line

Comment: Add 160 (0A0h). Forget int 21h/9 and linefeed - they won't play nicely together. No need to reset `ds`. Seems like you had the space in the right place, but reverted to the first line for 'a'.

Comment: so it work to start new line but i need to do the to write each letter per one line which i dont know how to start over after mov [0a0h], ' '

mov [0a2h] , 'l'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a. You need to remove this line entirely because it does not contain executable code and thus will crash your program!

```
linefeed db 13, 10, "$"
```

b. Did you notice you skipped an address?

```
mov [0ch], ' '
mov [010h], 'N'
```

c. Asking DOS to do a linefeed is useless here because you are writing directly in the video memory.  So loose these lines. Moreover it would still have failed because DS was not pointing to the program itself!

```
mov ah, 09
mov dx, offset linefeed
int 21h
```

d. Just continu this sequence...

```
mov [0A2h], 'l'
mov [0A4h], 'a'
mov [0A6h], 's'
mov ..........
```